# Software to scale and rotate drawings without losing resolution

Tags: vector, software-recommendation

I am looking for software that will let me draw a very simple design and then convert it into different sizes and rotations without losing resolution. The goal is to lay a number of these out into a pattern. I'm not sure if I need to go for something as sophisticated as Illustrator. Will you kindly make some suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org), since it is easy to use and free (Open Source), therefore easy to try. It's a Vector-Editor, so scaling is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is any kind of software that handle vector graphics. Here's a long list, pick one that meets your criterias (price etc.):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors